# Any better solution for this scheduling algorithm?

Tags: algorithm

You have N persons. Each person has a list of free time periods.

For example, Person 1's free time periods might be [(9, 9.5); (11, 12.5)] which means he is free between 9 and 9:30 and between 11:00 and 12:30.

You want to find a time period so that you can gather all N persons together and have a meeting of 2 hours.

write a method:

*input:*

> a list of list, each list inside is the free time period list of a
>   person

*output:*

> one or more time period that you can use to have the N persons meeting
>   for 2 hours; or you cannot find such a time period

---

What I think of is like this:

- merge two persons' time period lists in the following way: if two time period doesn't overlap, then remove the one that has early start time; otherwise, put the overlap part (a new time period) to the new list and remove the one that has early start time. Continue the merge.
- After merging finishes, we get a new list with the time overlaps of two persons, then merge it with the 3rd person, so on so forth until all lists are merged.
- scan the final merged list and find out the 2 hours slots.

This algorithm is **O(N*M) if assume each person has `M` free time periods.

---

**Is there any better solution?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input has size of N*M, so you cannot get any better time complexity - you have to read all the input.

---

Initially I misread the question and posted the algorithm below; it's has a time complexity only slightly bigger than input size (`O(nm log nm)`), but solves more general case, when you want to maximize the number of people on the meeting if they cannot meet all at once.

```
1. Merge periods (a, b), (b, c) into (a, c)
2. Forget periods shorter than 2 hours
3. Transform your input into list of 
    (timestamp_of_beginning, person_id, True)
    (timestamp_of_ending - 2 hours, person_id, False)
4. Sort the list by first element of tuple
5. Iterate over the list, with a set A, 
   adding person_id to A on (_, person_id, True),
   and removing on (_, person_id, False). 

   If after processing some item (t, _, _) 
   A has k elements, you can have a meeting of k persons, their ids are in A.

6. The maximal size of A during iteration is the maximal number of persons 
   that can have the meeting.
```

Comment: What's the time complexity?